# How do I fix this Youtube live embed? I am using Youtube-api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been using Youtube to stream for many years. Just this past weekend, my embed no longer works on https://quentinroad.org/watchlive/. I feel like there is an issue with the Youtube-api connecting to the live embeds only. Regular embeds work just fine. Is anyone experiencing this issue or know how to fix it?

I have tried creating new API. I have tried 2 separate Wordpress plugins and a straight embed code. I have also tried this on other sites with different hosts/not wordpress and same results.